# Exporting only the cited references from word to Iatex

Tags: bibtex, convert, mendeley

I have completed writing a research paper in MS word using the Mendeley Desktop plug-in. Now I have to convert all the references I used into bibtex. I know how to convert them one by one from Mendeley Desktop app. But can I export only the cited references all at once somehow?

Thanks in advance!